# How can I make the switch activate the password attribute?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to create a switch in kivy which when activated allows you to see the password. So I want the code to apply True to the password attribute of my loginscreen password textinput , when the switch is turned off password textinput and vice versa. If there is any other way that can solve my problem, please do tell me. I am a beginner at python and kivy.
This is my python code:-

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.switch import Switch
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
import json, glob
from datetime import datetime   
from pathlib import Path
import random
import re

Builder.load_file('design.kv')

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def sign_up(self):
        self.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        self.manager.current = "signup_screen"

    def login(self, uname, pword):
        with open("Emotional Quoter/users.json") as file:
            users = json.load(file)
        if uname in users and users[uname]['password'] == pword:
            self.manager.current = "login_screen_success"
        else:
            self.ids.login_wrong.text = "Wrong username or password!"
    
    def view_pass(self, instance, value):
        if value is True:
            self.ids.password = False
        else:
            self.ids.password = True

class SignupScreen(Screen):
    def add_user(self, uname, pword):
        with open("Emotional Quoter/users.json") as file:
            users = json.load(file)
            if len(pword) < 8:
                self.ids.wrong_password.text = "Make sure your password is at lest 8 letters"
            elif re.search('[0-9]', pword) is None:
                self.ids.wrong_password.text = "Make sure your password has a number in it"
            elif re.search('[A-Z]', pword) is None: 
                self.ids.wrong_password.text = "Make sure your password has a capital letter in it"
            elif uname in users:
                self.ids.wrong_password.text = "Username already exists"
            else:
                users[uname] = {'username': uname, 'password': pword,
                'created': datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")}

                with open("Emotional Quoter/users.json", 'w') as file:
                    json.dump(users, file)
                self.manager.current = "sign_up_screen_success"

class SignupScreenSuccess(Screen):
    def success(self):

        self.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
        self.manager.current = "login_screen"

class LoginScreenSuccess(Screen):
    def log_out(self):
        self.manager.transition.direction = "down"
        self.manager.current = "login_screen"

    def get_quote(self, feel):
        feel = feel.lower()
        available_feelings = glob.glob("Emotional Quoter/quotes/*txt")

        available_feelings = [Path(filename).stem for filename in 
                            available_feelings]

        if feel in available_feelings:
            with open(f"Emotional Quoter/quotes/{feel}.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file:
                quotes = file.readlines()
            self.ids.quote.text = random.choice(quotes)
        else:
            self.ids.quote.text = "Try another feeling"

class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

and this is my kivy code:

```
<LoginScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        padding: 15, 15
        spacing: 30, 30
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            Label: 
                font_size: "30sp"
                text: "User Login"
                bold: True
            TextInput:
                size_hint: (.2, None)
                height: 50
                multiline: False
                id: username
                hint_text: "Username"
            RelativeLayout:
                TextInput:
                    size_hint: (.9, None)
                    height: 50
                    multiline: False
                    id: password
                    hint_text: "Password"
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.45, 'center_y': 0.4}
                    password: 
                Switch:
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.96, 'center_y': 0.43}
                    active: False
                    on_active: root.view_pass(self, self.active)
            RelativeLayout:
                Button:
                    text: "Login"
                    on_press: root.login(root.ids.username.text, root.ids.password.text)
                    size_hint: 0.3, 0.5
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
            Label:
                id: login_wrong
                text: ""
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
            padding: 10, 10
            spacing: 10, 10
            Button:
                text: "Forgot Password?"
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
                opacity: 1 if self.state == 'normal' else 0.5
                color: 0.1, 0.7, 1, 1
                bold: True
            Button: 
                text: "Signup here!!!"
                on_press: root.sign_up()
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
                opacity: 1 if self.state == 'normal' else 0.5
                color: 0.1, 0.7, 1, 1
                bold: True

<SignupScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'back.jpg'
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Label:
            font_size: 30
            text: "Signup for a space adventure!!!"
            bold: True
        TextInput:
            id:username
            hint_text: "Username"
        TextInput:
            id:password
            hint_text: "Password"
        Label:
            id: wrong_password
            text: ""
        Button:
            text: "Signup"
            on_press: root.add_user(root.ids.username.text , root.ids.password.text)

<SignupScreenSuccess>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'back.jpg'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: "Signup Successful"
        Button:
            text: "Login Page"
            on_press: root.success()

<LoginScreenSuccess>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'back.jpg'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Button:
            text: "Logout"
            on_press: root.log_out()
        Label:
            text: "How do you feel?"
        TextInput:
            id: feeling
            hint_text: "Things to try: Happy, Sad, Unloved..."
        Button:
            text: "Enlighten me!"
            on_press: root.get_quote(root.ids.feeling.text)
        Label:
            id: quote
            text: ""

<RootWidget>:
    LoginScreen:
        name: "login_screen"
    SignupScreen:
        name: "signup_screen"
    SignupScreenSuccess:
        name: "sign_up_screen_success"
    LoginScreenSuccess:
        name: "login_screen_success"
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem with your code is a minor error in the `view_pass()` method. In your code, `self.ids.password` is a reference to the `TextInput`. But you actually want to change the `password` property of that `TextInput`. Here is a corrected version of that method:

```
def view_pass(self, instance, value):
    if value is True:
        self.ids.password.password = False
    else:
        self.ids.password.password = True
```